# Case when statement to conditionally populate columns in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark as show below:

```py
df6 = df_n_a \
        .withColumn("x", explode_outer(col("x"))) \
        .withColumn("y", when( \
            col('x.e')=='S',  lit(None).cast("string")) \
                    .when(col('x.e')=='C', element_at("m.n.o", -1))) \
            .select(
                from_unixtime(col("x.w")).alias("w"),
                col("x.e").alias("e"),
                col("y"),
        )
```

I want to populate the column 'y' as NULL if `x.e` is 'S', and if it is 'C' then populate it with a logic using element_at since it is an array. The problem here is that when execution begins, even when `x.e` is 'S' the 'when' for the input as 'C' gets executed. This is producing a key missing error, as records of type 'x.e'=='S' in input JSON won't have the keys m.n.o. Is there a way to strictly impose a logic wherein, if `x.e`=='S' then make it NULL and not to continue with the next when statement. I've tried with otherwise after the first when and it still won't work. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add some sample input and expected output?